# Google line graph, define shaded area

Tags: google-visualization

I have a normal line graph with 2 lines.  In addition, to the lines, I want to have a full height shaded area which would take up around 25% of the chart on the x axis.

Is this possible?

Comment: you could use a combo chart -- with an area chart series for the shading...

Comment: awesome, works perfectly with a few tweaks.  Thanks!